# What is the difference in calling an interface methods and struct methods in serveHTTP handler?

Tags: go

I'm moving from Java to go. In 'go', I got confused when using a Handler.

For eg: `ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)`

Here ResponseWriter is an interface and Request is a struct. We are using w as an object to call the methods in ResponseWriter interface. The same goes with req object. I know that a struct can implement an interface. Here I'm showing an example and where I'm getting confused. [Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/aCtPXRbGer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. The interface is the type of your variable/field/parameter; the value is still (most likely) a struct. This is the same as in Java, where you can specify that a method argument is of an interface type, but you must still pass in a concretion. Calling methods on the interface-typed argument is the same as calling the method on a concrete type.

Comment: To expand, interfaces are _essentially_ just struct which have no data fields, only methods, or at least you can think of them that way.  They can hold any type with implements the interface's methods, and the only thing you can do with that type is call those methods.  Calling those methods, however, is no different from calling methods on a struct.